# Fix for ProjectLibre incorrect critical path

Tags: bugs, critical-path, projectlibre

I'm a big open source supporter, and want to switch from MS Project to ProjectLibre, however it does not display the critical path correctly for projects above a certain size.  I'm wondering if anyone has a simple solution I've missed, or would be willing to look at the source code (on SourceForge) to find a fix.  I know it's not much, but I'd be willing to contribute a couple hundred dollars to a solution.

I asked the developers about the bug, however they are working on a paid cloud version and don't plan to fix the desktop version.  I posted this question a couple times on the ProjectLibre SourceForge issue tracker, but the developers kept deleting it, so I am looking for someone that is both PM and SW knowledgeable that could help.

The bug seems quite straightforward, a simple lack of update, so hopefully would be fixable by someone able to dig into the code a bit.  You can the bug clearly in this example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vx2ar21xd16lzt0/ProjectLibre%20bug.pod?dl=0

Among many other examples in the file, task 19 is linked finish to start to task 20, so task 20 should come after task 19, but it does not.  The workaround is to double-click on the link from 19 to 20, then just select "Ok" to close the popup, and then task 20 moves after 19.  But even then it is not shown in red as critical.  You have to double-click on the link from 19 to 20 again, then choose "Ok" to close the window again, before the critical path updates to red.  And then repeat for all problems in the schedule.  Not practical.

This is really fundamental functionality.  Until it is fixed, it would be dangerous to trust ProjectLibre with serious projects.  The PM worlds needs a good open source Gantt tool!  Anyone know a simple workaround I’ve missed, or is willing to see if they can fix the code?

Comment: I've given up on ProjectLibre.  The best open source Gantt application I can find is now GanttProject.  I tried importing a several hundred line example from Microsoft Project, and it seemed to work.  Most importantly, it is actively developed with more than two dozen contributors on their GitHub page, and that is key: https://github.com/bardsoftware/ganttproject